# Using A button in while loop to remove a specific database row

Tags: php, button, mysqli

I have worked on this for a few days now.
This snippet finds the correct row(s) from the database. It works fine. However, when the Button is clicked, I only want for the comment it is next to targeted, not all the comments on that page. It's hard to explain.. Let me show you image.
What I am doing currently is selecting the database rows and outputting them for debugging, instead of removing them *(I don't want to go around deleting sections of my database with broken code)*
[image]

`$db` is  `mysqli` connection to the database
Snippet of the while loop:
**TL/TR**
I want to do the following with this in the end:

- Remove the comment from the database.
- Give the feedback to an admin.

This may sound like a noob question, but please help me.
Many thanks!
Just can't wrap my head around this, made like 6 pages single-handed and now I am stuck in a thing this *"easy"* for a d**n week and i still can't get it right.

**EDIT**
Latest snippet (Still doing it, What the hell!?!)

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id='$id'");
    while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
 echo "<h5>".$row->name."</h5>","<br>";
$strip_comment = strip_tags($row->comment);
$delComment = $row->comment_id;
        $strip_comment_shlashes = stripslashes($strip_comment);
    echo "<blockquote>".$strip_comment_shlashes,"<br><br></blockquote>";
    //button stuff
    if($is_admin){
        $query1 = $db->prepare("SELECT comment_id FROM comments WHERE comment_id = '$delComment'");
        $query1->execute();
        $query1->bind_result($commId);
        while($row2 = $query1->fetch()):
    ?>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=$id"?>" method="post">
        <input type="submit" class="closeButton" name="deleteComment" value="<?php echo $commId; ?>" />
    </form> 
    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['deleteComment'])&& $is_admin){

        if($is_admin && $commId){
        echo "Comment ID <b>$commId</b> Removed";

        }

    }
endwhile;
}
```

**Edit: NON-OBJECT error..**

```
        $delComment_2 = $_POST['deleteComment'];
        $query2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_id='$delComment_2'");
        $query2->execute();
```

Edit 2: (31/10)

Please, Could someone fix this snippet and post it? I don't usually ask for working snippets, but this one is driving me crazy. I just am too noob to understand how this goes. Thanks.

Comment: are you deleting comment using ajax?

Comment: I don't see any query to delete any specific row, so I can't help you, as I am confused.

Comment: Im currently only selecting the rows and outputting them for debugging.

Comment: quick fix: `if($_POST['deleteComment] && $_GET['id']==$row->comment_id && $is_admin){}`, but I'd create more separation between actions (deleting) and display of content.

Comment: It seems that the `$id` that you want to refer on the `form` is the **comment** id, but you're selecting the **post** with that id that maybe has those two comments related. So the select brings you those two coments instead of what you want.

Comment: I'm still having issues with this... I've been trying to do it for 3 DAYS now. I'm really starting to give up on myself..

Comment: I think you first need to explain what you want to do. You want to delete a comment but keep a message saying "comment was removed" when the user visits the page? or are you just displaying the message as a feedback to the admin that just deleted the comment?

Comment: I just want to delete the comment from the database if the "X" button is set next to the comment, and display the administrator a one-time-message of "Comment ID `$id` was removed", if the removal was successful. 

However I'm having a hard time of linking the `X` button to that one comment it's next to. If I could get that done I'd probably be able to script the remaining on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the input to this:

```
<input type="submit" class="closeButton" name="deleteComment" value="$comment_id_here" />
```

And then just use the comment id to delete a specific one from the database. (check `$_POST['deleteComment']`)

Of course, there are numerous other ways to do this - but the point is the same: you need to pass the comment id (**not the post id**) from your page to the query string. Whatever way you use to accomplish that is up to you, I just gave you an example.

Comment: Damn it, It's still doing it for all the comments. I've included the latest snippet in the main post. To all my logic it SHOULD be perfectly working. I just cannot understand why is it doing for all the comments. If someone could edit and post a working version of my snippet, that'd be really great, since I am not able to understand this myself anymore.

Comment: Where are you reading $delComment from? Is the snippet your form landing page?

Comment: I've added the newest snippet, did it in a more sensible and hopefully understandable way this time

Comment: `echo "Comment ID <b>{$_POST['deleteComment']}</b> Removed";` that's thing I'm trying to tell you all along.

Comment: That works now, However, How do I use that `$_POST['deleteComment']` In a Query? When I try to do something like this:
`$delComment_2 = $_POST['deleteComment'];
    $query2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_id='$delComment_2'");`
It would show up as a non-object.

Comment: That looks fine, actually, are you sure the rest of the db code is working? Have you already deleted the comment before selecting it?

Comment: oh.my.god. I've broken it again. It broke overnight and wont work anymore. Perfect.

Comment: Sorry. I got a bit angry ( shouldn't have). I solved the issue by rewriting the whole page (<.<). Was worth it anyways. thanks. again sorry for that.

Comment: No worries. Just so you know, in case something similar happens again, it might be a better idea to open another question. Unless, of course, it's the same issue, and none of the answers work.